# Please display the number of views on the question page under the votes on the left side

Tags: feature-request, views

Please display the number of views on the question page under the votes on the left side.

It feels like it should be on the left under the number of votes and number of favorites.

Comment: I wonder if this should be tagged "status-norepro", or would we need a new tag like "status-invalid"... or "status-misunderstanding" :)

Comment: status-looktoright?

Comment: status-omg :-) "I asked myself the same question for a while actually"

Comment: Goddamnit.  At least fourty people know I'm an idiot now.

Comment: I was going to edit the title, but I couldn't dare overwrite that brilliant edit comment.

Comment: Maybe status-wtf?

Answer (score 6):

Umm, I do see the number ("viewed 5 times") right there, on the right-hand side of the page, below the tags, etc. Are you sure about this? :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can already see this on the right side of the screen underneath the tags. You have "Asked" for when the question was posted, "Viewed" for the number of views, and "Latest Activity" which posts the last time an answer or other activity was done.